# Allow Creation of new user account for program I'm building in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm just starting out with programming, and I;m doing a course in Visual Basic, I have run up against a roadblock in my knowledge and I'm finding it difficult to find the correct information online (mainly because of my lack of understanding of which question to ask at this point)

I have been set a task to create a windows forms program in visual basic 2012 that will allow a plumber to quickly generate a quote for any prospective job.

So far, so good.

I have successfully created a login page, that allows the plumber to login. using the following code.

```
    Dim varUser As String
    Dim varPass As String


    'login form'


    If txtUsername.Text = "Username" And txtPassword.Text = "Password" Then
        formQuote.Show()
        Me.Hide()


    End If
End Sub
```

I would now like to add button allowing a new user to create a new account and login, you know like you see on most programs and websites.

I know this will require a database of some sort and relevant code.

I'm sure there's tutorial or worksheet somewhere online - but i keep finding irrelevant and confusing information because I'm not certain of the right serach term.

Could anyone point me to a good source?

Thanking you all in advance

BANG!!

Answer (score 0):

Add A link label or Button 
And in that link or button

Call the registration Form

frmregister.show()